# Clicking an item hidden behind a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am setting up a script for a jQuery image carousel. I have implemented a rotation feature that is triggered by mouseover on two divs that divide the parent carousel by 2. If you mouseover the left side, it rotates one way, and vice-versa.

The issue is, with these two divs z-indexed to the top to provide that functionality, I cannot setup a click function when a user clicks a specific image to make it pop out.

The alternative I am thinking would be using PageX so that I may remove the divs and use the click function as planned. Is it possible to use PageX to split a div into 2 (so if you mouseover one side it performs one action, and the opposite on the otherside)? Or is there another method that would better suit this situation?

Comment: Please post come code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to split into two parts by using the mousepointers position and the position of the element to calculate what half was clicked. There's also pointer events that will let you click "through" an element, but it's not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would just put a single div behind the carousel and use the event.pageX as you said. If the coordinate is on the left side of the page, rotate left, else right.

If the images in the carousel aren't actually contained by the outer div (and won't bubble the mouseover), just attach the same mouseover event to them too.